# How to concatenate two dfs having a similar datetime column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dfs which have one identical datetime column. I want to concatenate columns from one df to another, skipping  where the data is missing. I want to print NaN for missing data.

I tried writing a while loop to concatenate. It gave this error:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

```
while df['TIMESTAMP'] == x['TIMESTAMP']:

    z = pd.concat([df,x],axis=1)
```

I expect to concatenate two dfs, x and df. df is full timestamp range and x has some missing values. I want to write the data from x to df w.r.t. datetime column. Write NaN for missing values.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate dataframes it will add one to the bottom of another:

```
DF1:

A B C
1 2 5
2 5 3

DF2:

A D E
1 2 3
3 4 7
```

Given my two example dataframes if you concatenate you will get

```
DF_Concat:
A B    C    D    E
1 2    5    NULL NULL
2 5    3    NULL NULL
1 NULL NULL 2    3
3 NULL NULL 4    7
```

Whereas a merge will return

```
DF_Merge:
A B    C    D    E
1 2    5    2    3
2 5    3    NULL NULL
3 NULL NULL 4    7
```

It sounds to me like you are looking for a merge:

```
pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='A')
```